# How can I calculate the top distance, for positioning a title, on top of another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my title to "stand on top" of another div, to get the below result. 
With position absolute it is possible, but to make it responsive, I need to check all breakpoints and set the position "hard-coded" (I don't know if you say it like this), but with changing font-size etc. this just doesn't seem really clean. 
Isn't there a way to calculate this distance with jQuery?

While I was trying to figure this out, I thought about measuring the height off .banner-dark with jQuery but then I have the distance to the bottom of this div, and I need the distance to the top of the title.
So it should be something like: "height of banner-dark"-"height of title".
But I'm not really sure how to do this :)

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a349dhkt/

```css
.banner-dark {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.article-white {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 128px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-dark">

</div>
<div class="article-white">
  <h1 class="title">SPECIAL TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

I expect that my title is exactly on the top of the second div on every single viewport.

Comment: Cant you just use bottom: 0?

Comment: something like `var dark = $(".banner-dark").height();` and `var article = $(".article-white").height();`

Comment: bottom: 0 , would place the title at the bottom of the body. not the bottom of the div.

Comment: Right, I see that now, if set your parent to relative and use the same height as the text you should be fairly close to what you want, give or take a few pixels and no need for jquery https://jsfiddle.net/embwt54g/1/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yes, that would give me the height of both divs, but how do I calculate the top distance to set the title? now I've set it manually to (top: 128px;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/an539fsg/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* get height of .title */
    var title = $(".title").height(); 

    /* get height of .article-white*/
    var article = $(".article-white").height();

    /* calculate distance */
    var new_height = article - title;

    /* apply to css */
    $('h1').css('top', new_height);  
});
```

Comment: Thx Adam. This was more or less what I needed :)